# What is the endpoint for AWS API IoT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-iot

I am trying tou figure out what is endpoint to AWS IoT API. I found this code in documentation to create API request, but i dont really know what to change to connect to AWS IoT API.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html . I would like to create thing for example using aws API.

Answer (score 0):

`iot.$REGION.amazonaws.com`

The `CreateThing` API is part of the Control plane: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html